# Creating users using MS Graph REST API v1.0 Exception handling

Tags: exception, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am creating users for B2C using Graph REST API. I am mapping the user object and using this line to create the user

```
var status = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);
```

I want to add exception handling but the `status` returns a `User` object.

Is there a better way to add users and how can I work in exception handling and is there a way to access the http code ?

here is an example of a response

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "id": "4c7be08b-361f-41a8-b1ef-1712f7a3dfb2",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userName",
      "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "federated",
      "issuer": "facebook.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
    }
  ],
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to use `try-catch` statement and handle `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException` when calling Graph API endpoint. It provides an [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.serviceexception?view=graph-core-dotnet#properties) about an exception from the service.

Instead of `GetAsync()` you can use an alternative method `GetResponseObjectAsync()`. It's a wrapper which allows you to access `StatusCode` and `HttpHeaders` of the response.

```
try
{
    var graphResponse = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddResponseAsync(user);
    if (graphResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        var newUser = await graphResponse.GetResponseObjectAsync();
    }
}
catch (ServiceException ex)
{
    // ex.Error.Message;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```